# How will I convert part of a dataframe to an json object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
val df = Seq((2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)).toDF("year", "month", "title", "rating")
```

I can convert the whole row to json like this.

```
val jsonColumns = df.select("year", "month", "title", "rating").toJSON
```

How can I get only the month, year and title in json and year to be out of the json object, but still part of the dataframe (so i can use it as partition column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How can I get only the month, year and title in json and year to be out of the json object, but still part of the dataframe (so i can use it as partition column)

You can use `to_json` and `struct` *inbuilt functions* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(to_json(struct(col("year"), col("month"), col("title"))).as("json"), col("year"))
```

You should get output as

```
+----------------------------------------+----+
|json                                    |year|
+----------------------------------------+----+
|{"year":2012,"month":8,"title":"Batman"}|2012|
|{"year":2012,"month":8,"title":"Hero"}  |2012|
|{"year":2012,"month":7,"title":"Robot"} |2012|
|{"year":2011,"month":7,"title":"Git"}   |2011|
+----------------------------------------+----+
```

**Updated**

`to_json` function would return a json string. If you require a json object then `to_json` function is not needed. Instead you can do the following

```
df.select(struct(col("year"), col("month"), col("title")).as("json"), col("year")).toJSON
```

Comment: Maharajan, thanks. Now when I write the data into a table with strict object it is not possible. cause it is only a string, not a json object. can you please tell me how do i convert this object and load it in a struct column.

Comment: @Srinivas, for that case don't use to_json function. just use struct as `df.select(struct(col("year"), col("month"), col("title")).as("json"), col("year")).toJSON` and you should be fine. And its not Maharajan, it Maharjan. And I am from Nepal.

Comment: @Maharjan, thanks for the reply. When I try this all the double quotes are backslashes like \”year\” and for this reason the hive table cannot read the data. Apologies for typing your name wrong, I assumed you were South Indian through your first name.

Comment: I don't use hive so I cannot tell you the extact solution. When I write to a text file its working fine. did you try removing .toJSON

Comment: @Maharjan, you are right, it is the same in my machine as well. It is hive’s inability to decipher \. I will try to write something like a json parser.

Comment: Thanks for your help